# Find samples containing a specific OTU

Tags: r, bioinformatics, phyloseq

In my phyloseq `tax_table` i have some interesting taxa I want to look further into. I want to use OTU number or taxonomic name to figure out which samples have this taxa present. I could just use the OTU# corresponsing to the taxa in `tax_table` and then go into `otu_table` to find the sample, but as you will all know, this is tedious and har to do.
Anny ideas? thanks

Comment: Please follow this guide to help the community help you solve the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is usually something like this:
Make a vector of the names/genera you're interested in, then subset them as a separate object, it makes it a lot easier to maintain overview.

```
temptax <- as.data.frame(tax_table(physeq)) #get your taxa
mytax <- rbind(temptax[temptax$Genus == "g_Fusarium", ], #pick whichever ones you're looking for
              temptax[temptax$Genus == "g_Symmetrospora", ], #works with rownames, too.
              temptax[temptax$Genus == "g__Ramularia", ])
mytax <- rownames(mytax); mytax #we only need the rownames to make up the vector
cooltaxa <- subset_taxa(physeq, rownames(tax_table(physeq)) %in% mytax) #subset based on this vector
cooltaxa #now gives you a phyloseq object with all the information for your chosen taxa
```

Hope this is useful.